# Multiple IF Then statements in Google Sheets

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets

I need to write the following in a manner that Google sheets will understand.

`IF C5 is between 500 & 749 then 1`
`IF C5 is between 750 & 1249 then 2`
`IF C5 is equal to or greater than 1250 then 4`

How do I do this?

Thank you

I have tried multiple examples online but I can't seem to get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

What if `C5<500`? I'll assume result should be `0`:

```
=if(C5>=1250,4,if(C5>=750,2,if(C5>=500,1,0)))
```

Result:

[image]

If there are more `IF`'s to consider you could use helper table with `VLOOKUP` as it helps to get rid of long `IF` nesting:

```
=vlookup(C5,$F$2:$G$5,2,true)
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I tried for several hours. This works great. Thank you also for the information about VLOOKUP. I have another project to try that on.